# Copy and Paste Scrip

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy data from COPY SHEET to PASTE SHEET and once complete I want to data in the copy sheet to clear.

**COPY SHEET INFORMATION**
Information is in Column B
Priority    A - High
First Name  New Test
Last Name   test
Company     JLC
Phone Number    3065551212
Email   jeckert679@gmail.com
Notes   Likes Coffee
Call Back Date  3/7/2022
Date Entered    3/26/2023
Address     679 Rink Ave, Regina SK  S4X2P3

**PASTE SHEET**
Information needs to be put into columns A-L

First Name  Last Name   Company     Phone Number    Email   Notes   Call Back Date  Date Entered    Address

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contact Form");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CRM");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(B1:B10);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(A2:L2);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);

  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `B1:B10` and `A2:L2` of `var source = copySheet.getRange(B1:B10);` and `var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(A2:L2);` are required to be set as the string.
- From your question, it seems that you wanted to copy the values of "B1:B10" to "A2:L2". In this case, it is required to transpose the values when the values are copied.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contact Form");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CRM");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange("B1:B10");

  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange("A2:L2");

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);

  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of "B1:B10" of "Contact Form" is copied to "A2:L2" of "CRM". And, "B1:B10" of "Contact Form" is cleared.
- For example, if you want to append the values to the destination sheet, please modify `var destination = pasteSheet.getRange("A2:L2");` as follows.

  ```
    var lastRow = pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(lastRow == 1 ? 2 : lastRow, 1);
  ```

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)